# Парсинг страницы и отправка нового запроса

Tags: c#, многопоточность, синтаксический-анализ

Решил начать изучение с# с написания небольшого парсера. 
Дабы во время получения данных с сервера софтина не "висла" использую метод `WebClient.OpenReadAsync()`. При получении данных страница парсится и отправляется новый запрос....но после отправки третьего запроса данные не приходят, ошибок не выдает, да и ничего вроде не виснет. Уже не знаю что делать. Может как то поток закрывать нужно или еще чего...

Упрощенная версия кода со ссылкой на яндекс и бесконечным циклом:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApplication1.classes;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        private WebClient client = new WebClient();

        private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");

            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(OnOpenComplete);

            GoParse();
        }
        private void GoParse()
        {          
            string url = "http://yandex.ru";            
            Uri myuri = new Uri(url);
            richTextBox1.Text += url + "\n"; 
            client.OpenReadAsync(myuri);            
        }
        private void OnOpenComplete(object target, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs args)
        { 
            richTextBox1.Text += "OnOpenComplete\n";             
            GoParse();
        }
    }
}
```

---

[[@STDray](/users/12057/stdray)](/users/12057/stdray)  Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А почему инициализация нового объекта типа WebClient происходит только в конструкторе? ЕМНИП, правильным будет создавать новый объект WebClient при новом запросе. Если у вас только один клиент, то надо следить за синхронизацией запросов, т.е. объект у вас еще занят, а вы уже его используете для следующего запроса - не помню, что именно будет в таком случае, но это точно ошибка.

Comment: многопоточность у вас отсутствует. присутствуют асинхронные запросы. И, как пишут в МСДН, в обработчике события вы ДОЛЖНЫ закрыть полученный поток (Result в OpenReadCompletedEventArgs) во избежание проблем.

Comment: uilenspiegel. Понял что нужно сделать, но не знаю как это правильно реализовать.

В GoParse() добавил client.CancelAsync(). Все работает нормально.

А как сделать что бы было красиво ? :) Или именно такой вариант вы и имели в виду?

Comment: @VladD, осталось только понять, зачем вы постите нерабочий код :)

Comment: @STDray: у меня не было под рукой компилятора, не мог проверить синтаксис. Вы придираетесь к мелочам или возражаете по существу?

---
Если вы про `Task.StartNew`, то да, надо `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

Comment: @VladD, будет под рукой компилятор - проверьте свой пример. Самостоятельно. Этот разговор не по существу мне надоел.

Comment: @STDray: Могу и самостоятельно, но тогда наш разговор опускается из сферы "как надо и как не надо" в сферу голого синтаксиса. Впрочем, воля ваша.

    private async Task<string> ParseResponseAsync(string input)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => parseResponse(input));
    }

(Я бы сказал, что возражения на уровне синтаксиса как раз и являются "не по существу".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я полагаю, что взяв для изучения "написание небольшого парсера" стоит фокусироваться именно на нем, а не распыляться, пытаясь попутно освоить работу с формами и многозадачностью в .Net.

Многозадачность - это большая и сложная тема. Если вы ещё не читали посвященные ей главы у Рихтера, то я рекомендую начать уже сейчас. На понимание уйдет много времени (и скорей всего придется неоднократно перечитывать), но чем раньше базворды по теме уложатся в голове, тем легче вам будет ориентироваться в предоставляемых платформой .Net возможностях.

На текущий момент самым удобным средством для выполнения параллельных задач является [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460717.aspx). Основой библиотеки является класс Task<T>, позволяющий асинхронно выполнять задачи и выстраивать их в цепочку (то есть после выполнения первой задачи, запускается вторая, получая результат первой как свой аргумент). Все подробности, вы можете прочитать на MSDN.

Если говорить конкретно о вашей задаче.
1) Используйте класс [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx), он изначально спроектирован для выполнения асинхронных задач и лучше подходит для подобных сценариев. В .Net 4.5 он есть в стандартной библиотеке, а для младших версий платформы вы можете подключить его через nuget.
2) Необходимо помнить, что доступ к элементам UI можно получить только из его собственного потока выполнения. Для этого нужно перед запуском асинхронной задачи получить планировщик задач UI-потока и передать его последней задаче в цепочке (которая обновит richTextBox) в качестве аргумента.

Примерно так будет выглядеть ваш метод

```
void parseAndUpdateRtb(string uri, TaskScheduler scheduler) {
    var client = getHttpClient();
    var task = client
        .GetStringAsync(uri) //получаем страницу
        .ContinueWith(t => parseRespose(t.Result)) // парсим результат
        .ContinueWith(t => richTextBox1.Text += t.Result, scheduler); //обновляем содержимое окна
    Task.Run(() => task); //запускем на выполнение цепочку задач
}
```

А его использование будет примерно таким

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); //запоминаем планировщик ui-потока
    var uri = "http://yandex.ru";
    parseAndUpdateRtb(uri, uiScheduler);
}
```

Полный код можно посмотреть [здесь](http://pastebin.com/vpNkdgEQ)
Конечно, это может выглядеть достаточно непривычно. Но пользоваться TPL можно даже без глубокого понимания принципов его работы. Просто поэкспериментируйте с созданием своих задач и следите за типами.

Comment: Хм, если уж говорить о текущем самом удобном средстве, то наверное ещё лучше async/await:

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = await getHttpClient().GetStringAsync(uri);
        richTextBox1.Text += s;
    }

Comment: @VladD, это не какое-то другое средство, это тоже самое. async/await - синтаксический сахар для работы с Task из C# 5, при котором начинается бардак с cancellationtoken'ами, условиями продолжений и другими параметрами. Кроме того, у в вашем примере блокирующий вызов.

Comment: Семантика та же, синтаксис намного проще. Ну так не на ассемблере же пишем.

А где у меня блокирующий вызов? (`richTextBox1.Text += s;` автоматически попадает в continuation, разве нет?)

Comment: Синтаксис не отражает всех возможностей библиотеки. Где семантика синхронизации в определенном контексте, где семантика выбора опций продолжений? А сахарка можно добавить и через query comprehension , только вот тоже не достаточно.
Что касается вашего примера, лучше реализуйте целиком и поиграйтесь с Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @STDray: Вас [пример из MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) не убеждает? Синхронизация в определённом контексте в данной задаче вовсе не нужна, а в общем случае делается средствами самого async-метода.

---
По поводу опций продолжений, это костыль, который больше не нужен, поскольку try-блок может содержать await, а исключения автоматически маршалируются.

Comment: @VladD,

    // The following method runs synchronously, despite the use of async.
    // You cannot move or resize the Form1 window while Thread.Sleep
    // is running because the UI thread is blocked.
    public async Task<string> WaitSynchronously()
    {
        // Add a using directive for System.Threading.
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return "Finished";
    }

А теперь попробуйте в моем варианте, добавить тот же самый Thread.Sleep(10000), например, в parseRespose и сравните поведение формы. Дальше сами решайте, нужен вам контекст синхронизации или нет.

Comment: Не-не-не, надо ж не так:

    private async Task<string> ParseResponseAsync(string input)
    {
        return await Task.StartNew(() => parseResponse(input);
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = await getHttpClient().GetStringAsync(uri);
        richTextBox1.Text += await ParseResponseAsync(s);
    }

Понятно, что метод должен быть асинхронным, в отдельном потоке за меня никто ничего не запустит.

Comment: @VladD, 
*>По поводу опций продолжений, это костыль, который больше не нужен*
Ох, лол. cancellationtoken'ы тоже костыль и не нужны?

Comment: @STDray: окей, рад, что мы договорились по поводу остального. Особенно если сравнить количество и ясность кода. Насчёт cancellation: `catch (OperationCanceledException ex)`? ([MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx), там разобран пример.)